# Why is _Dummy_ for return type when Generating a Persistence Mapping by Database Schema In IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, persistence

I Run the generate persistence mapping for one entity in the database (MySQL), but it always generate all the setter with a `_Dummy_` return type and return this. My entities are so many that I don't want to change them to the proper type or just return void by hand. So, what can I do?

```
public _Dummy_ setApplyId(int applyId) {
    this.applyId = applyId;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Dummy type is generated in cases when IDE does not know precise database type to map the corresponding Java type for it. 

Please invoke Synchronize action for the data source to make sure IDE introspected all database types and that the introspection has completed successfully.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you very much.